# PendingIntent no funciona en Notificacion

Tags: android

Tengo el siguiente método que me permite recibir  un Intent.

```
public PushNotifications setIntent(Intent intent) {
    int requestId = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    return this;
}
```

Aquí es donde creo la notificación y donde uso el pendingIntent previamente creado.

```
public PushNotifications create(String title, String contentText) {
    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "MO")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.logo)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(contentText)
            .setVibrate(new long[] {100, 250, 100, 500})
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    return this;
}
```

Esta notificación la mando a llamar desde un **Service** de la siguiente forma:

```
new PushNotifications(getThis())
                                .create(preferences.getString("nombre_proyecto", "..."),
                                        "Hay nuevo mensaje")
                                .setIntent(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MessagesActivity.class))
                                .show();
```

Al dar click en la notificación no se abre el activity **MessageActivity**, tampoco se produce ningún error.

Comment: Tu código es correcto, no veo algún problema solo asegura tengas definido el intent correcto en el pendingIntent y que la Activity a abrir este registrada en tu aplicación.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es importante definas correctamente el intent, en este caso tratas de abrir `MessagesActivity`, asegura que esta Activity este registrada

```
new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MessagesActivity.class)
```

**Si no se encuentra registrada en tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` la activity a abrir, al dar clic en la notificación, no mostrará error pero no abrirá la Activity.**

```
<activity android:name=".`MessagesActivity`"/>
```

---

Para dispositivos con Android 8.0 o mayor te sugiero agregar :

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("default","Channel name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
    channel.setDescription("Channel description");
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}
```

Revisa este ejemplo que abre una activity al dar clic en la notificación:

[Android - crea notificación](https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-Create-Notification)