# ¿Como lanzar diferentes actividades con Push Notifications?

Tags: java, android, push-notification

Buen día como podría abrir una actividad dependiendo de lo que se requiera con las notificaciones de Firebase?

Originalmente el **pendingIntent** puede abrir una actividad predefinida pero en mi caso necesito abrir la notificación dependiendo del tipo de notificación que reciba el usuario

Por ejemplo quiero que vaya a mi actividad de reportes cuando estoy dentro de la aplicación pero quiero que vaya a login cuando estoy fuera, también que viaje a una actividad de chat cuando estoy dentro y a login cuando estoy fuera lo que quiere decir que necesitaría varios intents diferentes desde el pendingintent, ¿hay manera de hacer algo así usando la misma clase FCM? nose si validando algo en especifico o algo asi.

Este es mi codigo:

```
public PendingIntent clicknoti(){

    mensaje = 1;

    Intent nf = null;

    if (Login.cargo == 1){
        DatosPrincipales.gIdEstado = 2;
        nf = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ObtenerReportesAdmin.class);
    }

    else if (Login.cargo == 0 && gIdUsuario > 0) {
        obtenerEstado();
        nf = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ObtenerReportes.class);
    }

    else if (Login.cargo == 0 && gIdUsuario == 0){
        nf = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
    }

    nf.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    return PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestCode++, nf,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

}
```

Como se han dado cuenta estoy usando mi base de datos para validar el intent pero ahora que necesito un par de intents mas ya no me funciona porque la validacion solo me sirve para un par de activitis no para todas entonces no se si existe otra manera de hacerlo o una mas factible.

Clase completa:

```
public class Fcm extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onNewToken(@NonNull String s) {
    super.onNewToken(s);
    Log.e("token","mi token es:"+s);

}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    String from =remoteMessage.getFrom();

    if (remoteMessage.getData().size()>0){
       String titulo=remoteMessage.getData().get("titulo");
        String detalle=remoteMessage.getData().get("detalle");

        mayorqueoreo(titulo,detalle);

    }
}

private void mayorqueoreo(String titulo, String detalle) {
    String id="mensaje";
    NotificationManager nm=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,id);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel nc=new NotificationChannel(id,"nuevo", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        nc.setShowBadge(true);
        assert nm!=null;
        nm.createNotificationChannel(nc);
    }

    
    //Nuevas lineas agregadas
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ObtenerReportesAdmin.class);

    //Trate de agregar otro intent pero solo le puedo pasar 1 parametro a .setContentIntent
    Intent notificationIntent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ObtenerReportesAdmin.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),0,notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    builder.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentTitle(titulo)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logotaqueria)
            .setContentText(detalle)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentInfo("nuevo");

    Random random=new Random();
    int idNotity =random.nextInt(8000);

    assert nm !=null;
    nm.notify(idNotity,builder.build());
}

public PendingIntent clicknoti(){

    //He quitado todo el codido del metodo clicknoti pero me pide un valor de retorno. ¿Debo eliminar este metodo?

}
```

}

Espero me puedan ayudar de antemano muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro del `PendingIntent`, define el `Intent` que previamente creas para abrir la `Activity` que deseas:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ObtenerReportesAdmin.class)

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),0,notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

El PendingIntent lo defines a tu Notificaciòn:

```
/* Construye la notificacion */
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(            getApplicationContext()).setWhen(when).setContentText(notificationContent)
        .setContentTitle(notificationTitle).setSmallIcon(smalIcon)
        .setAutoCancel(true).setTicker(notificationTitle)
        .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Revisa estas respuestas:

[Como hago para hacer un Intent dentro de cuerpo de una notificación en android?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/35739/95)

[PendingIntent en Notificacion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/233579/95)

Comment: Hola Elenasys gracias por la respuesta y los links que me facilitas, una duda la variable pendingIntent donde la tengo que pasar como parametro?

Comment: Lo defines en la notificaciòn mediante .setContentIntent(pendingIntent); para que al dar clic ejecute el intent, actualicè la respuesta.

Comment: Comprendo gracias ahora veo que se define una actividad en el metodo por lo tanto si defino las demas activityes como el metodo va a diferenciar hacia donde va a viajar cada activity?

Comment: Ya he editado la pregunta según lo me dices talvez puedes identificar donde esta incorrecto el código

Comment: Para diferenciar cada activity simplemente define intents diferentes,  tu pregunta se resuelve con lo que comento en mi respuesta, si tienes una nueva pregunta puedes realizar otra y hacer referencia a esta. Acabo de ver tu eres la persona que ha estado publicando preguntas sobre notificaciones. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/495405/notificaciones-push-en-android-con-firebase-utilizando-el-token

Comment: Bueno igual gracias por la respuesta voy a tomar otro rumbo en cuanto a esta parte según lo que me dices, si yo he hecho un par de preguntas relacionadas a las notificaciones, hay algún inconveniente? si es asi házmelo saber, saludos